# XSL-FO: Can fo:marker be used to store anything?

Tags: xml, xslt, xsl-fo, dita

This question is part XSL-FO, part XSLT, and part DITA. In general, this question is an attempt to troubleshoot what I am doing wrong with `fo:marker` and to understand if what I am attempting is possible.

I'm attempting to use fo:marker to store text from a specific element and then retrieve that text in the header like you might expect. I'm doing this as part of a custom style sheet that is part of a DITA plugin. The idea is the plugin is for a document that lists a bunch of steps for procedures. The steps to these procedures generally include a bunch of pictures. So, the requirement is that when a step breaks across a page, the first sentence of the step acts as a running header of sorts. In DITA, the first sentence of a step is captured in a `cmd` element. So, my thought was I could setup the template that processes `cmd` elements with an `fo:marker`.

Here is what the template for `cmd` looks like with the marker I've added:

```
<xsl:template match="*[contains(@class, ' task/cmd ')]" priority="1">
    <fo:block xsl:use-attribute-sets="cmd">                     
        <xsl:call-template name="commonattributes"/>             
        <xsl:if test="../@importance='optional'">
            <xsl:call-template name="insertVariable">
                <xsl:with-param name="theVariableID" select="'Optional Step'"/>
            </xsl:call-template>
            <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
        </xsl:if>
        <fo:inline>
            <fo:marker marker-class-name="current-step"/>
        </fo:inline>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>            
    </fo:block>
</xsl:template>
```

This doesn't work. I played around with this a bit and was only able to get this to work on `info` elements, which is a sibling to `cmd`, when I modified the template like this:

```
<xsl:template match="*[contains(@class, ' task/info ')]">
    <fo:block xsl:use-attribute-sets="info">    
        <fo:inline>
            <fo:marker marker-class-name="current-step">
                <xsl:apply-templates/>
            </fo:marker>
        </fo:inline>
        <xsl:call-template name="commonattributes"/>            
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </fo:block>
</xsl:template>
```

The thing is, I tried this construction with the `cmd` element (i.e. include an apply-templates instruction) and it still produces nothing.

Is what I describe possible and why does my marker only work when I include a apply-templates instruction and only for the `info` element?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need something inside the `fo:marker` because it's the content of the `fo:marker` that "may be retrieved and formatted from within an fo:static-content ... using an fo:retrieve-marker".  See http://www.w3.org/TR/xsl11/#fo_marker

I don't know why an `fo:marker` with content and with the same marker class name isn't working in both contexts.  Are you using `retrieve-position="first-including-carryover"` on the `fo:retrieve-marker`?  Did you leave in the `fo:marker` for `info` such that it's masking the `fo:marker` for `cmd`?

A completely separate alternative might be to put each step in a single-column table with no borders and put the content of the `cmd` in the table header.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback @tony. I did actually try this as a table header first but that complicated things in that I'm already using tables in how the steps themselves are constructed. One of the other requirements is that the images for a step need to exist side-by-side with the relevant instruction. I figured using markers would accomplish what I want without compromising the step structure too much. In general, would you say that using a header or marker is the only realistic way I can accomplish what I am attempting?

Comment: You can put `fo:table` inside `fo:table-cell`, but since you're already using tables, you could presumably combine markers and tables and use `fo:retrieve-table-marker (http://www.w3.org/TR/xsl11/#fo_retrieve-table-marker) to retrieve a marker set in the current table.

Comment: Thanks Tony. Based on your feedback, I was able to work out how I was using fo:marker incorrectly.